# Load image from xcassets without knowing the name

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, xcasset

I have multiple images in my asset catalog as shown below. Is there a convenient method to load the images without using a hardcoded string every time:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
images.append(UIImage(named: "South_America-Argentina")!)
images.append(UIImage(named: "South_America-Bolivia")!)
images.append(UIImage(named: "South_America-Brazil")!)
// ...
```

[image: xcassets]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to load images from xcassets without knowing the name. One way would be to store the image names in **enums** as @totiG already mentioned but with more than 100 flags this would be very time consuming.

Fortunately there is a library who already did this for us: [FlagKit](https://github.com/madebybowtie/FlagKit)

Answer (score 0):

One way to store your image names is with enums. I have provided 2 ways of doing this below - the 2nd one gives you a nice grouping.

```
//Method 1
enum CountryFlags: String {
    case Argentina = "South_America-Argentina"
    case Brazil = "South_America-Brazil"

    var image: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: self.rawValue)
    }
}

//Method 2
enum CountryImages {
    enum SouthAmerica: String {
        case Argentina = "South_America-Argentina"
        case Brazil = "South_America-Brazil"

        var image: UIImage? {
            return UIImage(named: self.rawValue)
        }
    }
    enum Africa: String {
        case Egypt = "Africa-Egypt"

        var image: UIImage? {
            return UIImage(named: self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let method1Image = CountryFlags.Argentina.image
let method2Image = CountryImages.SouthAmerica.Argentina.image
```

If your images were named differently however, eg by country code, then you could get a list of country codes and just loop over the list to load the images. So if you needed to load the flag for Argentina with code AR, you would use UIImage(named: "AR")

Comment: The problem is that i have more than 100 flags and I would have to write a case for each of them.